# could have done it

Tags: subjunctive-mood, could

1. I really could have done it, if you had come earlier.
2. I could really have done it, if you had come earlier.
3. I could have really done it, if you had come earlier.
4. I could have done it really, if you had come earlier.

Q1. I wonder if there is or are any wrong sentence(s) here either grammatically or unnaturally.
Q2. 'could have' usually can be contracted like "could've", if so, adverbs like 'really' can not go in there.
Q3. Is the expression "could really have done it" wrong?
The fact that could have is contracted to "could've" makes me tend to believe it's wrong.

Comment: Only the first one would slip past my internal grammarometer — and even then it might be classed as "for informal use only". :-)

Comment: I like #1, and I like #2. The fact that 'could have' can be contracted to *could've* does not prevent another word from sneaking in.

Comment: After reading your question, I believe you only need 2 and Q3; the other sentences are fine, and you know it, and the other questions are unnecessary. However, the comma before "if" is disputable.

Comment: @niamulbengali and Yosef Baskin and ralph.m Thank you much for the advices. By the way niamulbengali read my question and my mind perfectly.

Comment: It's actually supposed to be "could *of* done it", I believe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of your four options, the first one sounds most natural, the second isn't bad (but is a split infinitive), the third sounds awkward, and the fourth seems to need another comma before "really." Let's examine why. The inclusion of the word "really" is rather unnecessary, unless the speaker believes the listener has doubts about the truth of what they are saying. I imagine the conversation this way: "I could have done it." "No, you couldn't." "I really could have done it, if you had come earlier." So, you should put "really" before the phrase that needs the emphasis "could have done it" - rather than in the middle of that phrase or after it. If you use the fourth option - "I could have done it, really, if you had come earlier" - it doesn't sound convincing, like you don't even believe yourself, because the "really" is sort of an afterthought.

Comment: Thanks for your precious comment. 2nd sentence is "Awkward" What could awkward mean?